# How to correctly describe a function that returns a new class built on the basis of a description in the form of an object

Tags: typescript

Here is an example of the code:

```
function generator(prototype) {
  const cls = class { };

  if (prototype.$name) {
    cls.name = prototype.$name;
  }

  // converting a prototype code ...

  cls.prototype = prototype;

  return cls;
}

const MyClass = generator({
  f1: '2',
  _f2: {
    $default: ''
  },
  f2: {
    get() {
      return this._f2; //this: any
    },
    set(v) {
      this._f2 = v; //this: any
    }
  },
  f3: {
    $type: String,
    $default: 'asd',
    get() {
      return this.f1 + this.f2; //this: any
    },
    set(v) {
      this.f1 = v[0];
      this.f2 = v[1];
    }
  },
  m() {
    return this.f3; //this: any
  },
  $static: {
    s1: 'static',
    s2: {
      $def: 'static 2'
    },
    s3: {
      get() {
        return 'static 3'
      }
    }
  }
});

console.log(MyClass.s1) //Property 's1' does not exist on type 'typeof cls'
console.log(MyClass.s2) //Property 's1' does not exist on type 'typeof cls'
console.log(MyClass.s3) //Property 's1' does not exist on type 'typeof cls'
const o = new MyClass();
console.log(o.f1) //Property 'f1' does not exist on type 'cls'
console.log(o.f2) //Property 'f2' does not exist on type 'cls'
console.log(o.f3) //Property 'f3' does not exist on type 'cls'
console.log(o.m()) //Property 'm' does not exist on type 'cls'
```

Converting a prototype is essentially just bringing incomplete descriptions of properties to a general view.

How do I describe the generator function in typescript so that typing works?

although the typescript language allows you to describe types very well, it is possible to use generics, but there is not enough work with reflection and with such a construction as class.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/weyzEw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Wow, this is practically what I need. in fact, the question is a little more extensive. prototype contains not only properties described directly, but also descriptions that can be called descriptors with getters, setters, etc., and properties can be collected into named groups.

Comment: It's not really great to expand the scope of the question after someone suggested a possible solution; if this was something you needed, I'd have expected it to be in the question to start with.   If you really do need to expand the scope of the question, please [edit] the question to clarify your requirements (and hopefully commit to not adding more).  But I hope instead that I can write up this as an answer and if you have a followup question you can post a new one.  Let me know how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: Oh too bad you went ahead and expanded the scope.  Well, [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8QYVN) is the closest I can get with your example.  Note that it is correct for the compiler to complain about `MyClass.s1`, because your function does not actually put anything there.  If there's code you need to give typings to, please include the actual code.  Or describe it in enough explicit detail for someone to figure out the typings for you.  Keep in mind that I might not be able to commit to working on it, if it gets too complicated to be a good SO question for future readers.

Comment: I am not interested in a specific particular solution, but in the principle of how a template can be described, implying the generation of a class based on a json object, but despite the fact that the description of fields from this object is obtained not as is, but with some transformation.

Comment: Without a [mre] I don't know how to proceed; I'm not inclined to try to guess at what things you might need to do and describe the guiding principles in devising a potential solution.  Either a specific concrete example is presented or I don't have enough details to help, sorry.  Good luck!